# How does the reference work in visual studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I feel like this is really a newbie question since I am really new to Visual Studio.

[This is my solution with 2 projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyQqT.png)
I was trying to use Patient class(a class in Patient.cs)in AddPatient.aspx.cs, so I added the PatientPackage as a reference to WebSite1.

[The error in AddPatient.aspx.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn4E9.png)
However, it didn't work as intended as I am trying to use the class in AddPatient.aspx.cs.

[namespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlnDy.png)

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: what is the error it give you???

Comment: are you asking how you can add a project reference to a website project? that is hidden on one of the tabs of the website project's property dialog. please show the class declaration of `PatientPackage` with namespace, if possible not as a picture.

Comment: This is an asp.net project btw

Comment: Its says "PatientPackage" could not be found.

Comment: It says "PatientPackage" could not be found. @omriman12

Comment: check the `namespace` in `Patient.cs`. Is it `PatientPackage`?

Comment: @dlatikay I did add a reference by right clicking on Website1

Comment: Please edit your question to include the namespace of the class you are trying to reference as showing in your code

Comment: @AjayGupta It wasn't and I changed it. But it still not working in AddPatient.aspx.cs

Comment: @YudongLi Are you getting the same error now?

Comment: @TheGeneral I just edited my question

Comment: @AjayGupta Yes. It still has the error.

Comment: Also unless you really need to show something visual, always add code to your question not images, clicking images are annoying. if you really feel the need to add an image. Add them into the actual question and not a link

Comment: @TheGeneral I will work on that, sorry. I am pretty new to the programming industry overall.

Comment: up next would be code review. I recommend to use automated tools for validation, and follow the guidelines. examples: start identifier names with capital letters, do not initialize class members unnecessarily (`private ... = null;`) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding the namespace and the name of the class

```
using PatientPackage; // Will be sufficient
```

This is about the time you need to visit the documentation

[Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/)

[Using Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces)

[using Directive (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)

[Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)